# Why would an iPad not render HTML5 video inline, though the video is viewable when I go to the address of the file?

Tags: ios, html, video

I've been frustrated by trying to get an HTML5 video to play on an iPad. At first, I assumed it was a codec problem, but even after following all advice I could find on the internet to fix it, it still wasn't playing. However, I realized that it's not a problem with the codec, as shown by this: the video doesn't render inside the main page, but if I go to the link where the media file is stored, it does show. Here's the offending code:

```
<video autoplay loop controls id="hipplay-video" class="video-top">
    <source src="wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Hipplayapple.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Hipplaywebm.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Hipplayogg.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 video tag.
</video>
```

If you have an iPad and you go to http://www.hipplay.com - the video at the top does not play. However, if you visit http://www.hipplay.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Hipplayapple.mp4, the video plays just fine.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that iOS does not like when you insert your own controls with JavaScript AND doesn't like it when you autoplay videos. When I turned those features off (using a poster instead), everything worked as expected.